# How to design content blocks which render HTML content as tumblr does?

Tags: html, templates, themes, tumblr, handlebars.js

To create custom themes tumblr uses content blocks to render HTML.
For e.g

```
<html>
 <body>
    <ol id="posts">
        {block:Posts}
            <li> ... </li>
        {/block:Posts}
    </ol>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is one example but they seem to have an extensive design which tends to take care of every piece of content. Check here - http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes

How can you design something like this for your own platform whereby you have some predefined content which you want to make available to public using these kind of content blocks mainly to enable easy development of custom themes.

Iam particularly interested in learning about the underlying technology and the design principles. Is something there we can already use or we have to work on something from scratch?

I believe we have something like handlebars which provide you with a template mechanism but is it the right approach to do something as custom as the above implementation.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about *template engines*.

There are many.

See Wikipedia’s [comparison of web template engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines). For more about the concepts, see the article [Web template system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system).